# The difference between initialize and self.new

Tags: ruby

Sorry, I wasn't sure how to explain to explain this. What is the difference (if any) between the two pieces of code below?

```
class Foo
  def initalize
  end
end

class Foo
  def self.new
    allocate
  end
end
```

Furthermore, what's the difference between the two ways to initialize a class below:

```
Foo.new
Foo.allocate
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059552/classallocate-and-its-uses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`allocate` *allocates the memory* for an instance of `Foo` but **does not initialize** it.

`initialize` is called on an already allocated object to initialize (set the initial values of) an instance of `Foo`.

The default implementation of `new` calls both of these:

```
class Foo
  def self.new(*args, &blk)
    obj = allocate
    obj.initialize(*args, &blk)
    obj
  end
end
```

*Note: The default implementation of `new` is usually written natively (e.g. in C, for MRI), not in Ruby. The snippet above is the Ruby that has the same effect as the native implementation.*

So you see, the two are not quite the same, although they are both used in the construction of a new instance of `Foo`.

If your `initialize` method was empty to begin with, and it took no arguments, then yes, you could just replace your definition of `Foo.new` with what is essentially an alias of `Foo.allocate`, but in all other cases, only by calling `Foo.new` can you get a properly initialized version of your object.

(I would recommend to sticking with just calling `new` on your classes, even if they don't require initialization, because it abstracts away the allocation of memory).

Comment: `new` also passes along its block if you pass one.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I used to think that initializing and allocating were the same thing, because the return values were similar.